# Make only (2) checkboxes in a datagridview column checkable at a time

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

I have set up a form in which I have a column of checkboxes in the right column. The left columns contain data that is read-only if the corresponding checkbox column is unchecked and editable when checked.  Since the data columns are dependent on each other for calculations I need (2) checked rows of the data columns editable at a time.  I would like the checkable boxes to be limited to any (2) with the remaining boxes to not be checkable until at least one of the checked boxes is unchecked.  I figured the best way would be to keep a running total of the number of checked boxes and somehow limit this, but I'm stuck at how to accomplish this.  The code below just outputs a persistant GlobalVar.NumChecked = -1 value. Any help or direction would be appreciated.

```
    private void dgvParameters_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView dgPG = dgvParameters;

    if (e.RowIndex < 0) return;

        GlobalVar.NumChecked = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvParameters.Rows)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex < 0) return;

            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = row.Cells[5] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;
            if (cell.Value == cell.TrueValue)

            {
                GlobalVar.NumChecked += 1;
                break;
            }
            if (cell.Value != cell.TrueValue)
            {
                GlobalVar.NumChecked -= 1;
                break;
            }

        }

        label2.Text = Convert.ToString(GlobalVar.NumChecked);  //Debug output
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't wait until the cell's `Value` changes by handling the [`CellValueChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) event. Handle the [`CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) event instead to cancel assigning the new value (true) by calling the [`CancelEdit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.canceledit?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.CancelEdit)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) method if you have two checked cells already.

```cs
// +
using System.Linq;
// ...

private void dgvParameters_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dgvParameters.CurrentCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell &&
        dgvParameters.IsCurrentCellDirty &&
        !(bool)dgvParameters.CurrentCell.FormattedValue)
    {
        var count = dgvParameters.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .SelectMany(r => r.Cells.OfType<DataGridViewCheckBoxCell>()
            .Where(c => (bool)c.FormattedValue))
            .Count();

        if (count == 2) dgvParameters.CancelEdit();
    }
}
```

If you have more than one `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` in the grid, then you need to specify that in the query as well.

```cs
private void dgvParameters_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int tarCol = 2;

    if (dgvParameters.CurrentCell is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell &&
        dgvParameters.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == tarCol &&
        dgvParameters.IsCurrentCellDirty &&
        !(bool)dgvParameters.CurrentCell.FormattedValue)
    {
        var count = dgvParameters.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .SelectMany(r => r.Cells.OfType<DataGridViewCheckBoxCell>()
            .Where(c => c.ColumnIndex == tarCol)
            .Where(c => (bool)c.FormattedValue))
            .Count();

        if (count == 2) dgvParameters.CancelEdit();
    }
}
```