# C# Allow user to use checkbox column to select one row in each DataGridView on a form

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I am new to C# and Visual Studio and am building a application which interacts with data.

I am trying to get my head around the intricacies of DataGridView controls.

I'm basically trying to build a "mapping" interface whereby an user can map a column from one table to a column in another table (in a different database).

I have two DataGridView controls on a form, one for each of the 2 databases being interacted with.
Each DataGridView is populated using a SqlDataAdapter and DataTable, which is triggered by selecting a table name from a corresponding combo box.

The corresponding grid displays the column name and datatype of each column in a data table.

So essentially the user will have 2 grids showing the columns of a table from each of the 2 databases.

I have added a checkbox column to each DataGridView, and so the user can only select one row from each data grid I have set the VirtualMode property of each grid to "True".

However, at runtime, the checkbox column in both grids is behaving like a set of Radio buttons, thus only allowing the user to select ONE checkbox across both grids.

Is there any way I can remove this limitation?

The mapping aspect of the work I'm trying to do is going to be difficult, but if I can't get around this, I'm going to have to re-think my approach. I was basically going to try, one at a time, to build a SQL INSERT INTO statement through code so I'd end up with something like

```
INSERT INTO TargetDB.dbo.TargetTable (TargetFieldA, TargetFieldB, TargetFieldC) 
SELECT SrcFieldA AS TargetFieldA, SrcFieldB AS TargetFieldB, SrcFieldC AS TargetFieldC FROM SourceDB.dbo.SourceTable 
EXCEPT 
SELECT TargetFieldA, TargetFieldB, TargetFieldC FROM TargetDB.dbo.TargetTable;
```

But that's probably for another question. As I said, I'm very new to C# so am probably approaching this all wrong anyway.

I haven't written any code yet to get around this as I was hoping I was just overlooking a setting or something. The only thing I have tried is placing each DataGridView control inside its own Panel, as I do with Radio buttons to ensure they "group" together and are not affected by the checked property of a radio button outside the panel. But that didn't work.

Many thanks in advance.

Regards

Steve

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73649966/14171304